# Понимание работы скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть картинка, стоит задача сделать её **"выполняющей"**.

Скрипт переключения темы оформления *(это для того, чтобы пользователь на тыкал в форме Перейти, а просто нажал бы на картинку и перешёл)*:

```
$('.switch_version a').click(function(event) {
    $('#block-switchtheme-switch-form #edit-theme').val('название_темы');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#block-switchtheme-switch-form .form-submit').click();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Что конкретно означает:

```
'.switch_version a'
'#block-switchtheme-switch-form #edit-theme'
'#block-switchtheme-switch-form .form-submit'
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73277/discussion-on-question-by-novi4ok---).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перечисленное относится к "селекторам", используемым для позиционирования jQuery на элементах DOM. Иными словами с помощью селекторов мы "говорим" jQuery - с каким элементами страницы необходимо выполнить дальнейшие действия.

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ. я правильно понимаю, что элементы с решётками - это для id, а без решетки с точкой в начале - для класса?

Comment: Верно. А без точки, решетки или двоеточия - это тэги, например в '.switch_version a' - тэг <a>. В данном случае выбираются все потомки элементов с классом "switch_version".

Comment: ага... а как мне тогда обратиться к картинке на странице? я должен заменить в $('.switch_version a') тэг <а> на <img>? и вместо .switch_version прописать свою картинку?

Comment: Если бы Вы добавили к вопросу код HTML, было бы намного проще Вам помочь.